# Can I use a case statement like this?

Tags: mysql, count, case

I don't have access to test this out at the moment, but haven't found any relevant examples.
I want to try something like this:

```
SELECT member.name, DISTINCT member.id, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN member.code = 'A' 
     THEN 1) AS CountACode, ... CountBCode, COUNT(*) as CountTotal  FROM member
```

I understand that I could do this differently, but I have a few other involved columns that I am already using and this would be so much more easier to do. However I believe I was told I was wrong without any indication of why. Would someone mind telling me where the issue is?

Comment: The case statement itself is fine (minus the missing `END`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not wrtite `DISTINCT` clause in between it has to be ummediately after `SELECT` clause.

yes you can use `CASE WHEN` statement inside `COUNT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT member.name,  member.id, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN member.code = 'A' THEN 'something..' END) AS CountACode, 
       ... CountBCode, 
       COUNT(*) as CountTotal 
FROM member;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the `DISTINCT` which applies to the entire result set, not just a single field.

For the count, the normal pattern for this is to us `SUM`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Condition = value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT member.name, member.id, SUM(CASE WHEN member.code = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS CountACode, ... CountBCode, COUNT(*) as CountTotal
FROM member
GROUP BY member.name, member.id
```